Total messages available in the DLQ is higher, but when I poll it's always lower
I have a FIFO SQS queue and a FIFO DLQ as well. The DLQ shows that it has 24 messages available, but when I poll the messages in the DLQ (with poll frequency to 50), it shows just 10 messages. All the messages has same messgeGroupId.
Also the messages in the source FIFO queue is consumed by a lambda and when it throws an error (with maximumReceiveCount of 1), the message is not shown on the DLQ as well.
Any idea on what could be happening?
Tried polling in higher batches and also tried to send a message to DLQ by throwing an error from lambda.

What do you mean by "it shows just 10 messages"? Where are you seeing this message count? Is it in the SQS console? It is likely that the ReceiveMessage() call used by the console has a Batch Size of 10. I wouldn't be too worried about what happens in the console -- the main thing is to get your code working.

A message will go to a Dead Letter Queue if it has failed multiple times, as determined by maxReceiveCount. So, the message might reappear in the source queue after the invisibility timeout has completed. Given that you are using the same MessageGroupID for all messages, and a ReceiveCount of 1, your Lambda function will not be given any more messages until it has either successfully processed a message or it has failed to process the message maxReceiveCount times (after which it will be removed from the source queue and sent to the Dead Letter Queue).

It's possible the message could have a hidden visibility configuration, or a delayed delivery configuration.
